# Can you construct a future-continuous verb tense?

Tags: verbs

I wanted to say "I'll be logged into Skype every night." So, I said 「毎夜、Skypeと **つながっている** つもりです。」 But now I am thinking maybe the verb tense should have been 「毎夜、Skypeと **つながる** つもりです。」

My sense is that「 毎夜、Skypeとつながっているつもりです。」 means (1) shift forward to each evening, and then state what I will be doing at that time in the continuous tense.

I sense that 「毎夜、Skypeとつながるつもりです。」  means (1) shift forward to each morning or afternoon, (2) state with the future tense (つながる) what I will be doing even later on that day in the evening (be on Skype). So, this feels like a double future. Does that make sense?

In summary, once "つもり" shifts the context into the future, can you use the continuous verb tense?

Comment: Why use つもり at all?

Comment: @非回答者 Now that I think about it, that is a good point. Forget the continuous tense option, then drop 「つもり」。「毎夜」 creates the future context. ok. But, what if I wanted to introduce some uncertainty? I plan to be on Skype, but I can't guarantee it. Does 「つもり」 carry that meaning?

Answer (score 1):

First 毎夜 isn't so common. 毎晩２３時ごろ or some such would be must more common. Second, つながっている is not continuous, but rather perfect aspect (completed action where the effect or state continues into the present).

If you want to strongly establish a future context, why not use something like これから or 来週 or some such? つもり talks about your intent or plans for some future time and sounds a little strange here IMO; maybe not wrong, but just not usual?

If you mean that until some specific future time point you will not have been connected to Skype, but from now on you're planning to be connected every night, you could say something like:

これからは毎晩ずっとSkypeとつながってることにした。

> I've decided that from now on I'll be connected to Skype all night
>   every night.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the concept of "perfect" verb tenses does not exist in Japanese. The "perfect" tenses embed adverbs that establish points in time using helping verbs and participles. Japanese verb tenses are so uninformative, there is not even a future tense. Some sentences don't even have verbs, much less verb tenses. Other than calling what "might" be the future continuous tense the present perfect tense, this answer is very useful. thank you.